# Simple average in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This seems like it should be pretty simple but I'm a little confused:

Here is my javescript and html:

```
<script>


var n, m, l, ave;


var mean = function() {

    // get input data
    n = +document.getElementById("Number one").value;
    m = +document.getElementById("Number two").value;
    l = +document.getElementById("Number two").value;

    // get the average
    ave = (n+m+l)/3;

    // output result   
    document.getElementById("ave").innerHTML = "Your average is: " + ave;}
```

Then the html

```
    <label>Data one:<input type="text" id="Number one"></label>
<label>Data two:<input type="text" id="Number two"></label>
 <label>Data three:<input type="text" id="Number three"></label>
<input type="button" onclick="mean();" value="Your average">
<div id="ave"></div>
```

The math doesn't work though. Don't know why. Please help.

edit: thanks everyone for helping with my dumb typo

Comment: What is wrong? Show us the result

Comment: the average of 4,6,8 is supposedly 5 and one third

Comment: Look at your `getElement` statements. The 3rd is a copy of a 2nd.

Answer (score 2):

Copy/paste error.  You read from "Number two" twice.

Incidentally it's kind of weird to have spaces in ids.  :)

Comment: Yeah, that shows up a lot...

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for the second number twice

`l = +document.getElementById("Number two").value;`

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, you use "Number two" twice change `l = +document.getElementById("Number two").value;` to use "Number three"

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to declare the function as a var, you can do it like this if you wish:

```
function mean(){//...code}
```

Declaring it as var is only needed if you wish to supply it to another function as an argument. The way you wrote also prevents you to call the function before it's definition, but that is a more advanced topic. If you want to know more read this: https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/

And then, you are geting the value on the "Number two" input two times. It should be:

```
n = +document.getElementById("Number one").value;
m = +document.getElementById("Number two").value;
l = +document.getElementById("Number three").value;
```

instead of:

```
n = +document.getElementById("Number one").value;
m = +document.getElementById("Number two").value;
l = +document.getElementById("Number two").value;
```

Comment: _First of all you don't need to declare the function as a var_. This is very misleading as the way the function is defined doesn't affect it's behavior. I think you should edit that part out.

Comment: That is why i put it like, if you wish. But i will expand it to explain better.